# What do we call the "repetition" construct (if it's even proper English)?

Tags: repetition

I've sometimes seen this construct, used to avoid repetitive handwriting, but I don't even know if it's proper English.

If it is, what is the name of this construct? I have no idea what to search for when looking it up...

> - Don't forget to buy eggs.
> - "        "  " " yogurt.
> - "        "  " " milk.

Comment: Questions that can simply be answered by quoting or linking to a dictionary definition are off topic here. Please see the [faq] to learn more about what the site is for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> [***ditto***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ditto)  **1**:  *a thing mentioned previously or above —used to avoid repeating a word —often symbolized by inverted commas or apostrophes*
>   **2**: a ditto mark

Comment: Oh LOL I didn't know it's called a ditto! Haha that makes total sense, thanks!

Comment: @Mehrdad: Note that the marks don't work unless they're lined up directly beneath the word being dittoed.

Comment: @Robusto: Yeah i tried to do that in the question.